# Issues migrating project from django 1.5 to django 1.8

Tags: python, django

I'm building a project with Django 1.5.1 and decided to migrate the project to Django 1.8.4, then I found out I cant initialize the project, I was able to detect and fix some errors, but It's been a couple of days now and I can't figure out the rest.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/jaime/djcode/spid/preventivos/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from preventivos.views import *
  File "/home/jaime/djcode/spid/preventivos/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from preventivos.forms import *
  File "/home/jaime/djcode/spid/preventivos/forms.py", line 122, in <module>
    class UnidadesForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/home/jaime/djcode/spid/preventivos/forms.py", line 124, in UnidadesForm
    ciudad = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'size':'13', 'onchange':'this.form.action=this.form.submit()'}), choices= RefCiudades.objects.filter(provincia__contains = RefProvincia.objects.filter(descripcion__contains = "CHUBUT").values("id"))  )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 679, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 697, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1309, in add_q
    clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1337, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1149, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1035, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1372, in names_to_path
    if field.is_relation and not field.related_model:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 60, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 110, in related_model
    apps.check_models_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this site requires that you post your questions in *English* only. Please translate this yourself; someone else translating for you will not help you understand comments and answers, or respond to feedback.

Comment: Alternatively, wait for the new [Spanish Stack Overflow site](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/21519/the-stack-overflow-in-spanish-project-is-underway) to be launched.

Comment: Please add the type of errors you're getting. Por favor agrega los errores que estas recibiendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback is telling you that the problem is this line in your `UnidadesForm` model form.

```
ciudad = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'size':'13', 'onchange':'this.form.action=this.form.submit()'}), choices= RefCiudades.objects.filter(provincia__contains = RefProvincia.objects.filter(descripcion__contains = "CHUBUT").values("id"))  )
```

As it's a model choice field, it would be better to use the `queryset` argument rather than `choices`.

```
ciudad = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'size':'13', 'onchange':'this.form.action=this.form.submit()'}), queryset= RefCiudades.objects.filter(provincia__contains = RefProvincia.objects.filter(descripcion__contains = "CHUBUT").values("id"))  )
```

I think that might stop the error, but I'm not sure that your queryset makes sense. The filter argument `provincia__contains` should take a string, but `RefProvincia(...).values("id")` will return a values queryset.

Comment: Thanks! i will try with that.

Comment: in my  RefCiudades model, the provincia field is a fk to RefProvincia, and i was passing this: 
[{'id':1L}] 
and it needed to receive just one id. I modified my original code to this: 
ciudad = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'size':'13', 'onchange':'this.form.action=this.form.submit()'}), queryset= RefCiudades.objects.filter(provincia__contains = RefProvincia.objects.filter(descripcion__contains = "CHUBUT").values("id")[0]['id'])  )
 
and it works. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Glad you got it working. There's a small problem that the query is going to run when the server starts, not when the form is shown. It would be better to move the `queryset` into the `__init__` method, but that would be better answered on a different question where you show your models.

Comment: Ok thanks for your recommendation, i will try with that.